# How to use FULLTEXT in mysql innoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, full-text-search

Sorry, if my question is naive, but it has puzzled me, and cannot benchmark the performance.

I want to use the newly introduced feature of innoDB for FULLTEXT index. I wonder what is the difference of

```
FULLTEXT(title,body)
```

and

```
FULLTEXT(title),
FULLTEXT(body
```

Is there any effect on the search performance and the ranking of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For InnoDB,

```
FULLTEXT(title,body) -- useful only for MATCH(title, body) AGAINST ...

FULLTEXT(title) -- useful only for MATCH(title) AGAINST ...
```

So, if you are doing both types of `MATCH`, you need both indexes.